# Script to reorder vertex indices

Tags: scripting, vertices

I need to reorder vertex indices on an object.  I suspect a python script is required but writing python is beyond me.  The object is a "roadway", five vertices wide and thousands of five-vertex rows in length (see image).  I want to reorder vertex index with "0" at first vertex on right, "1" - "4" on same row to left, and "5" at right in second row, etc.  I reordered the first four rows using [mesh][sort_elements][reverse] for illustration.

I'm hoping this is straight-forward coding for someone that knows python and Blender, and i'd be extremely grateful for the help.  I used to love writing code but Fortran 77 is not helpful here!
[image: Object vertex layout with indices]

Answer (score 0):

You need an object with identical geometry, although not necessarily same shape, which has the desired vertex indices.  In my case I was able to create one by cleaning up a  few vertex indices using [mesh] [sort elements] on a different object.  Then, use this nifty add-on that allows one to copy and paste vertex indices from one object to another. https://bartoszstyperek.gumroad.com/l/copy_verts_ids